# Change circuit breaker for dual purpose fitting

Tags: electrical, fitting

I have a power breaker fitted with a ducted outlet to exterior wiring. It is in white plastic, same size as twin socket, with push switches for on/off test/restart and neon light. I would like to change this for a similar unit with an integral switched plug socket for interior use to fit the same wall box. What do I need to ask for?

Comment: You want to mount an interior outlet to the exterior?  Don't.  Unless I'm misunderstanding the question.  Please clarify. Also, please specify country so we know what' we're dealing with.

Comment: Your terms ring strangely in the air. Please supply photos. National context might also help, as Chris Cudmore suggests.

Comment: So you have a [GFCI receptacle](http://img.ehowcdn.com/article-new/ehow/images/a08/2g/er/gfci-receptacle-outlet-types-800x800.jpg) that feeds power through to and exterior location, and you want to change the GFCI receptacle out for a [GFCI with a switch](http://i21.geccdn.net/site/images/n-picgroup/LEV_7299-NW.jpg)?

Comment: All you'll need to ask for is an Electrician.